# Inbound calls to one line cause other line to ring

Tags: telephone

**Scenario:**

- Residential
- Two VOIP telephone lines served by two Cisco SPA-122
  boxes
- Each SPA-122 connects to separate Line 1 and Line 2 junctions
  in the house basement
- A single, 2-wire cable connects a wireless
  telephone to Line 1
- A single, 4-wire cable connects a 2-line desk
  telephone to Line 1 and Line 2

**The problem:**

Inbound calls on Line 2 will ring Line 1 once and display the CID on the wireless telephone during the CID cycle.

In other words, BOTH Line 1 and Line 2 ring and display CID on inbound calls to Line 2.

The Line 1 wireless telephone only rings once, even as the line continues to ring Line 2 on the desktop phone.

**Tried:**

Completely disconnecting the Line 1 SPA-122 from the circuit. Problem happens.

Completely disconnecting the desk telephone, down to disconnecting the wires from the wall jack. Problem happens.

Completely disconnecting the 4 wire cable that supplies the desk phone from the basement junction box. *Problem does not happen*.

Connected a new length of 4 wire cable to the junction box and tested with it still wound on the spool, leading no where. PROBLEM HAPPENS.

It's as if inbound calls on Line 2 are jumping / inducting cross-copper to Line 1 and ringing the wireless phone! Is this possible? How can it be fixed?

Comment: You don't have any call forwarding or other call management options enabled by accident by any chance?

Comment: No. Even if so, my completely disconnecting service to the rogue-ringing would have revealed that.

Answer (score 2):

Is the 4 wire cable the type with 2 twisted pairs? If so, you may have the jacks wired incorrectly, such that the each telephone circuit is using 1 wire from twisted pair A, and one wire from twisted pair B. This would lead to increased and perhaps excessive electrical coupling from pair A to pair B.

If the 4-wire cable does not have 2 twisted pairs, then using a 2-twisted pair cable will reduce crosstalk between your two lines (provided you make sure that line 1 uses twisted pair A, and line 2 uses twisted pair B).

Comment: The cable is not twisted-pair, it's simple, green, red, black, yellow 4-conductor. I'm very confident that I have tip & ring wired correctly for both lines.  Not being twisted-pair made me consider that something is inducting across the wires but I've never experienced such problems in runs under 50 feet.  The circuits are not grounded. Could this be an issue? Should the tip or ring side be connected to ground?

Comment: The tip and ring should never be bonded to ground. They are intended to be a balanced pair for transmission purposes, and either are sometimes momentarily grounded by the central or station equipment (telephone or PBX) as a means of signalling (off hook, dialling, etc., but not usually in residential circuits), so if you ground either one you may prevent proper operation.

Comment: I agree with this answer, just because someone Has not seen it cross couple in the past in runs under 50' dosent mean anything with newer equipment that is more sensitive. The proper and suggested way to wire voip is to use twisted pair last time I checked at least cat 5 rated cable. +

Answer (score -2):

Evidently, the two VoIP base units and any satellite (extension) phone units have the same Bluetooth name. It is probably not the offending base unit that is ringing, but its satellite phones. The satellite (extension) phone stations are linked to its respective base unit, but since both base units have the same ID name only one base unit will ring, but all extension phones will ring because they will receive a signal from either of the base units. 
 The fix: Rename one of the base units and link its satellite units to the new name.

Comment: Bluetooth is generally not used for Wireless phones (you may be thinking of DECT), plus it appears that the two-line phone is fixed - there is only one wireless phone.